# puppet mysql user permissions trouble

Tags: mysql, permissions, puppet

I'm using Puppet to setup mysql and some users.

```
database_grant { "${db_user}/${dbname}":
  privileges => ['all'],
  require => [ Database_user[$db_user], Database[$dbname] ],
}
```

Where $db_user and is something like `test@localhost` and $db_name is `test_v3`.

What I'm trying to do is give this user permissions on all hosts or in other words `test@%`, but that doesn't seem to be working. Anyone have any ideas? I tried running puppet with just changing `test@localhost` to `test@%` but that didn't seem to do anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I must have not saved the file on the puppet environment that I was working on because changing it to `test@%` ended up working!